# How to debug ajax view in production?

Tags: python, ajax, django, debugging, deployment

I have this view which only responses on AJAX requests:

```
def ajax_product_details_like_prods(request, product_id):
    like_prods = None
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_id=product_id)
    # Haystack
    if product != None:
        like_prods = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(product)[:15]    
    html = render_to_string('ajax/product_details.html', {"most_visited": like_prods})

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

This code works on local dev server, but it throws `500 error` in dev-tools console when I try to access page with that AJAX on my production server.
**More details:**
1) This view uses `Haystack+Whoosh` connection:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'whoosh_index')
    },
}
```

And this seems to be ok - when I run `manage.py shell` and print `settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` - i see a right path.
2) There are all needed indexes in `whoosh_index` folder. They are generated on my local machine and then uploaded to prod. But I think that might work cuz I tested to copy indexes and they worked on local.
**How can I check on what stage this AJAX view fails?**

Comment: As a poor mans solution, you can use a `try`-`except` statement and in case of an exception return a JSON object as response with the exception (or something similar)

Comment: By default 500 errors in production should send you error mails with the error detail and traceback (if you properly configured your mails)

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers I did not set smtp server yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Poor man's solution: return the exception in the answer

A *poor mans solution* is to **return the exception as an answer** (do this only at a test stage! Since it exposes potentially information a hacker can use).

```
from traceback import format_exc

def ajax_product_details_like_prods(request, product_id):
    try:
        like_prods = None
       product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_id=product_id)
        # Haystack
        if product != None:
            like_prods = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(product)[:15]    
        html = render_to_string('ajax/product_details.html', {"most_visited": like_prods})

        return HttpResponse(html)
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': repr(e), 'traceback': format_exc()})
```

## Logging tools

This of course is not really a good solution for a server in production: it exposes details you probably want to hide. Furthermore, a user will only get confused.

You can use logging tools like *Sentry* and add the application to your Django installation. In that case it will create a new issue if there is en exception that is not catched by you.

Comment: I used the first your solution, just changed `JsonResponse` to `HttpResponse` and now I see only `MemoryError()` appeared, without any details. Can you explain what does that mean? This is a first time i see this error.

Comment: @Chiefir: well apparently your application runs out of memory. I edited the code, so now it can print the traceback. You should investigate what causes the program to consume that amounts of memory, or perhaps increase the memory on your server.